Low rank matrix completion with additional constraints
I have an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ of the form
$$ \sum_{i=1}^r \pi_i \frac 1 {1 - s_i} (1 - s_i)^\top,$$
where the $s_i$'s are $n \times 1$ vectors with positive entries that sum to 1, $1 - s_i$ is the vector $(1 - s_{i,j}: j \in [n])^\top$ and $\frac 1 {1 - s_i}$ is the vector $(1 / (1 - s_{i,j}): j \in [n])^\top$. In addition $\pi_i > 0 ~\forall i=1,\ldots,r$ and $\sum_{i=1}^r \pi_i = 1$.
I observe $n / 2 \gg r$ rows of $M$.
Can I compute the unobserved rows via a procedure that only relies only on standard linear algebra subroutines (SVD, finding eigenvectors, etc.). Specifically, I don't want to use any optimization procedure based on gradient descent.

The problem can actually be simplified to: given a matrix $A$, how can I find a unique decomposition of $M$ of the form $\sum_{i=1}^r \pi_i \frac{1}{a_i} a_i^\top$ under the constraint that $\pi$ and the $a_i$'s are positive vectors that sum to $1$.
